# How can I convert a date field to number in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

In Google Data Studio I'm searching for a formula to transform a date field into a number field.

I have been trying several options like these but they don't work.

```
CAST(Date_field as NUMBER)
```

> Invalid formula - Cannot cast from DATE to DOUBLE

```
Date_field+0
```

> Invalid formula - Operator "+" doesn't support DATE + NUMBER. Operator "+" supports NUMBER + NUMBER.

`datevalue() or value()` also don't exist.

Precision: I'm looking for a solution without changing the original date field in the data source or the connection. Only with a formula.

The expected result is a continuous series of integer numbers like this (the zero reference point doesn't matter, as long as 2 consecutive days are incremented by 1.)

| Date_field | Expected_output |
| --- | --- |
| 23 Feb 2022 | 44,615 |
| 22 Feb 2022 | 44,614 |
| 21 Feb 2022 | 44,613 |
| 2 Jan 2022 | 44,563 |
| 1 Jan 2022 | 44,562 |
| 31 Dec 2021 | 44,561 |
| 30 Dec 2021 | 44,560 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Expected_output` values are how the underlying dates are formatted in Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets, which use the [1900 date system](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487#:%7E:text=these%20dates%20manually.-,The%201900%20date%20system,-In%20the%201900), where day 1 in Excel is 01 Jan 1900 while in Google Sheets day 1 is 31 Dec 1899 (day 2 is 01 Jan 1900), the reason being that "*[Excel incorrectly assumes that the year 1900 is a leap year](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/wrongly-assumes-1900-is-leap-year#:%7E:text=Microsoft-,Excel%20incorrectly%20assumes%20that%20the%20year%201900%20is%20a%20leap%20year,-.%20This%20article%20explains)*", thus 29 Feb 1900 exists in Excel but not Google Sheets (for this reason, 31 Dec 1899 will be used below).

The [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below recreates the values in the `Expected_output` field by using the [`DATETIME_DIFF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698749) function to find the difference between the values in the `Date_field` and fixed date, 31 Dec 1899 (explained above), that was created using the [`DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9697009) function which "*creates a date*" in the Year, Month, Day format; the `+1` was added to include n+1 days (to count the initial day):

```
DATETIME_DIFF(Date_field, DATE(1899, 12, 31), DAY) + 1
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5a347551-76ac-4e53-9ec3-b0e0efb01a01) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MDAd4X0wITnk3cT59Ogqr4uzjMHb3igIQubvRevaq8k/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 8]